# jquery delay and animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I have a form with submit button. It was working correctly. However now it has stopped working, please help.

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function() {

    $(this).delay(2000).animate({
            width: '90px'
        },

        'slow',

        function() {

            alert('Im an alert message');
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior? because your code works.

Comment: it is not delaying page now, directly going to server controller.

Comment: Yeah it is working, see this http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/Lo49768r/

Comment: check if `<input type="submit"`, this will submit the form directly. make it `<input type="button"`

Comment: I think may be you have two `#btnsubmit`

Comment: yes thanks Bhushan, it was submit now i have change, it works, however it was working before with input type = submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your form is getting submitted. You need to prevent the default action of submit button using [`e.preventdefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Like

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function(e) {

    e.preventdefault();
    $(this).delay(2000).animate({
            width: '90px'
        },

        'slow',

        function() {

            alert('Im an alert message');
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Yes its working, but now controller is not getting called by submit button on server. e.preventDefault();

Comment: @HimanshuTiwari - put `$('#your-form-id').submit()` after the alert to go to your controller(submit form) once the animation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, but you can try calling from btnsubmit onclick like this:

```
   <input type="button" id="btnsubmit" onclick="buttonClicked(this);" value="click Here" >
```

write your animation in buttonClicked function:

```
   function buttonClicked(thisObj)
      {
            $(thisObj).delay(2000).animate({
              width: '90px'
              },

             'slow',

             function() {

             alert('Im an alert message');
              }
             );
      }
```